# security of exposing an identity identifier to the public

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, security, owasp

I am working with an asp.net mvc application that holds data in a sql server database. It has a customer table which obviously stores customers on the system. The id for customers is an identity column that holds the unique identifier for the customers, which auto increments by 1 for each new record.

For certain controller actions in mvc app, the customer id is included. I understand in get requests, this creates a security loop hole. It enables external bodies to gain knowledge on the database structure etc.

It would cause great difficulty to alter from using the customer id to another more obscure field in controller actions. Are there any other ways of exposing the id in a secure manner? I was thinking about mapping the id to another id and storing it in session, exposing this alternative id but unfortunately session storage is not available to me. An in certain situations the exposed id may need to maintained past the users session. Another way that I have looked at is increasing the seed on the identity column to a number other than 1, lets say a random number of 88. This would mean the exposed id would mean less to the outside user.

Any thoughts or suggestions on the above?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, mapping to another id like Guid and passing the Guid should work fine.  You wouldn't need to "store" the CustomerId in session.  You could just use the Guid to call the CustomerId when you needed it again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I considered this approach but it would require change to current structure which I want to avoid if possible. Is your suggestion to include the guid with customer in the database table? So have an internal reference and an external reference to the customer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're really worried about it, just make sure it's only displayed on authorized actions (require user login). There's nothing inherently "insecure" about exposing a primary key, though. The key has no meaning outside the context of the database, and if someone has gained access to your database, then them knowing a particular customer's id is the *least* of your problems.